# PHP header не передает символов через URL

Tags: php, header

Есть функция:

```
function handle_error($user_error_message, $system_error_message) {
    header("Location: show_error.php?" .
        "error_message={$user_error_message}&" .
        "system_error_message={$system_error_message}");
    exit();
}
```

И я пытаюсь через нее передать информацию об ошибке, но у меня не получается:

```
handle_error("сервер не может получить выбранное вами изображение.",
    $_FILES[$image_fieldname]['error']);
```

Но если я отправляю такое текст, то у меня все работает:

```
handle_error("сервер не может получить выбранное вами изображение.",
    "ошибка");
```

Если так, то нет:

```
handle_error("сервер не может получить выбранное вами изображение.",
    "ошибка!");
```

Comment: Из-за `!` - знака не работает?

Comment: @And не тольк. Еще из-за `, . ! ' " `

Comment: Экранируйте данные с `urlencode`

Comment: Может ошибки передавать через сесси лучше?

Comment: @Ninazu да не..

Comment: @Antonio112009 Почему? Для этого есть какие-то противопоказания?

Comment: В урл лучше передавать код ошибки (цифровой), а на странице выдавать сообщение, соответствующее коду. Это мировая практика